# Mysql seperate table for each user. (Users enter data monthly, should this data go in a seperate table)

Tags: mysql

I am making a website in which users enter data monthly, this data is stored in a mysql database, with a date key, so it can be retrieved by date. It would be easier and more human readable when browsing this data to have a separate table for each user, however I'm pretty certain that doing that would be a bad idea. Can anyone confirm this and provide other solutions.

Comment: Why would it be a bad idea?

Comment: @ExplosionPills -- huh?  Assuming all fields are the same, just add a UserId column to the table.  Then you can easily query by user -- no need or reason to have separate tables for each user unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: I guess not a separate table per user, but rather a separate table for user histories

Comment: @ExplosionPills Yeah, that's what I meant by separate table for each user.

Comment: @handuel so what would be wrong with having a table for user histories?

Comment: I don't know, I was kind of checking if there was something wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do this? SQL will filter data for you... e.g. to get data for the current month:

```
select col1, col2, col3 from tbl1 where date_format(date_col, '%m') = date_format(now(), '%m')
```

Answer (score 0):

Then a new user would be a new table?

This:

1. implies DDL rights (CREATE TABLE) to your mysql site user (except if you do it manually or through some kind of crontab task)
2. doesn't make it parseable easily withouth mixing mysql user_schema tables and common dml operations whenever you want to retrieve all user's data, or simply know the list of users

Really the answer is not easy and not definitive but ideally, as a 'religious' opinion, I try to avoid model manipulation in my website's everyday's life.
Orient yourself towards meta-modelisation.

Hope it helped,

S.

Answer (score 0):

Using history tables can have an advantage, primarily when there is a performance reason to do so.  Generally speaking however, you don't have a need to separate current month's data with previous month's data unless you're planning on having a large amount of data (most RDBMS can easily support millions of records without performance implications).  *I would not recommend splitting the tables just for presentation purposes.*

You have to take other things into consideration as well with history tables.  For example, you'd need scheduled events to move the data from the current table to the history table.  If you alter the current table, you'd need to also alter the history table.  Also querying for all data can be a little more troublesome since you'd be using a UNION.

Seems easier to have appropriate table indexing on a single table and if needed, have a view of the current's month's data.

However, if performance is an issue, then I would agree moving data to a history table can be advantageous.